# How to I re-write this with arrays and apply functions?

Tags: r, plyr, apply

Appreciate any help improving the efficiency of this loopy code. Sorry!

I'm simulating a "variable life adjusted display". More details on this [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/operational-research/AnalysisTools/VLAD/VLADMethods).

When applied to surgery, this is a chart that acts as a running tally of the expected number of deaths minus the actual number deaths (e). Suppose a surgical procedure has an expected probability of death across a population of p=0.1. The performance of a surgical unit can be considered as a vector (r_(1:n)) of 0s and 1s, where 0 is a success and 1 is a death. On starting (r_0), e_0 = 0. If a patient survives, p is added to the running score. If a patient dies, 1-p is subtracted from the running score (e.g., where r_1=0, e_1 = e_0 + p; where r_1=1, e_1 = e_0 - (1-p).

As can (possibly!) be seen, if a given set of results have an overall probability of death equal to that of the population, the running score (e) should oscilate around 0. If the rate of death is higher than expected (more 1s), the trend of e is negative. If the results are better than expected (more 0s), the trend is positive.

```
# Simulate VLAD
# m=number of simulations, n=number of procedures, p1=expected mortality
#    p2=actual mortality

vlad_sim <- function(m,n,p1,p2){
  e<-matrix(nrow=n, ncol=m)
  e[1,]<-0
  r<-vector()
  for (j in 1:m){
    r<-rbinom(n,1, p2)
    for (i in 2:n){
      e[i, j] <- ifelse(r[i]==0, e[i-1,j] + p1, e[i-1,j] - (1-p1))
    }
  }
return(e)
}

# Test example using m=100, n=100, p1=0.1, p2=0.2
e <- vlad_sim(100, 100, 0.1, 0.2)
```

This code works and does what I want. I can make lovely plots with ggplot2. I would like to change those two for-loops to apply functions but can't work out how. To start it might be easier just to make a matrix of results of dimensions n x m:

```
r<-matrix(rep(rbinom(n,1, p2),m), nrow=n, ncol=m)
```

How do I then apply my function to this matrix? Thank you!

Comment: Should `a<-matrix(nrow=n, ncol=m)` be `e<-matrix(nrow=n, ncol=m)`?

Comment: Thomas, yes, thank you. Changed terms to match my description. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution applies the calculations row-wise. You will still need one for loop since the calculations in one stage are based on the result of the stage before. Furthermore, the code is more efficient now.

```
vlad_sim <- function(m, n, p1, p2){
  e <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = m)
  r <- matrix(sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), size = (n - 1) * m, 
                     replace = TRUE, prob = c(1 - p2, p2)), ncol = m)
  for (i in seq(2L, n)) {
    e[i, ] <- e[i - 1, ] + p1 - r[i - 1, ]
  }   
  return(e)
}
```

Comment: Sven, 2 orders of magnitude faster. Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.